# EntityFramework, problems to create entity with composit key

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, .net-5, scaffolding

I have a database first project and the context/entities are automatically generated with Scaffold-DbContext.

One table (Region_User) in the database is a cross reference table between User and Region, it contains only two fields UserId, and RegionId that together is the composit key for the table.

I'm currently trying to add a new Region_User to a user like below:

```
var userregions = new List<Region_User>();
userregions.Add(new Region_User { UserId = 1, RegionId = 1 });
user.Region_User = userregions;
```

and then try to save it to the database I get an error like:

> {"Entity type 'Region_User' is defined with a 2-part composite key, but 1 values were passed to the 'DbSet.Find' method."}

The generated entity Region_User only contains the fields UserId and RegionId..

How should I do to save a new row in the Region_User table?

Comment: That's not an entity, that's a many-to-many join table. In EF Core 5 and later [you no longer need to create a class for this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/whatsnew#many-to-many)

Comment: What is the actual full exception? How do you save the changes? `SaveChanges` doesn't have to use `Find`, it already has access to the metadata

Comment: I figured it out. It was the old code that I try to replace that hade a UpdateManyToMany, that is no longer valid for the functionality. Found it when you asked me how it is saved. Thanks!